# Sitecore WeBlog (aspnet WebService) security

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sitecore, sitecore7, weblog

My Sitecore environment has separate CM & CD servers, on different domains.  After installing the [WeBlog](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/WeBlog.aspx) module and setting up the configs as instructed, I'm getting the following error (highlighted on [this page](http://sdn.sitecore.net/forum//ShowPost.aspx?PostID=59274)).

> The request for security token could not be satisfied because
>   authentication failed.
>
> Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for
>   security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.

With the CM server behind a firewall, the easiest solution is probably to not worry about authentication, but I'm not able to get that working.  I'm now getting this error:

> The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the
>   action 'http://tempuri.org/ICommentService/SubmitComment' is incorrect
>   or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context
>   token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security
>   context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due
>   to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions
>   prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's
>   binding.

The CM server (server) web.config looks like this:

```html
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WeBlogBindingConfig">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
  ...
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Services.CommentServiceBehaviour">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
      <service name="Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Services.CommentService"
        behaviorConfiguration="Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Services.CommentServiceBehaviour">
          <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Services.ICommentService" bindingConfiguration="WeBlogBindingConfig">
          </endpoint>
      </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

While the CD server (client) web.config looks like this:

```html
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WeBlogBindingConfig">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
  ...
  </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
      <endpoint address="http://cmserver/sitecore modules/web/WeBlog/Comment.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Services.ICommentService"
        name="WeBlogCommentService" bindingConfiguration="WeBlogBindingConfig">
      </endpoint>
      ...
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I've been fighting with this for a couple days now, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thad

Comment: No, I wasn't able to solve this issue in the allotted time, so we ended up creating a WordPress instance on a separate server.